# How can I configure a 'hello world' example of nightwatchjs working in circleci?

Tags: nightwatch.js, circleci

I'm trying to set up a sample circleci build using docker-compose. Everything is working fine but when I try to add a nightwatchjs test, something is wrong with the nightwatch bootstrapping/install. No matter what I do I can't seem to be able to get nightwatch to fire off.

This is the error I get in circleci;

```
nightwatch -t /home/ubuntu/docker-compose/tests/nightwatch.js

/home/ubuntu/docker-compose/tests/nightwatch.js:2
    "test_settings": {
                   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at new Module (/home/ubuntu/nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/module.js:7:23)
    at new TestSuite (/home/ubuntu/nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/testsuite.js:17:17)
    at runTestModule (/home/ubuntu/nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/run.js:38:19)

at runNextModule (/home/ubuntu/nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/run.js:190:23) nightwatch -t /home/ubuntu/docker-compose/tests/nightwatch.js returned exit code 1
```

This is my circle file.

```
# circle.yml
machine:
  services:
    - docker
general:
  branches:
    only:
      - master # list of branches to build
      - develop
dependencies:
  override:
    - sudo pip install --upgrade docker-compose
    - sudo pip install --upgrade pep8 
    - docker-compose build 
    - wget http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
    - java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar:
          background: true
    - npm install -g nightwatch
test:
  override:
    - docker-compose up -d; sleep 10
    - pep8 --first tests/test.py
    - nightwatch -t /home/ubuntu/docker-compose/tests/nightwatch.js
deployment:
  hub:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - chmod +x ./build/build-docker-dev.sh
      - sudo ./build/build-docker-dev.sh
      - docker login -e $DOCKER_EMAIL -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASS
      - docker push xxx/dockercompose_odoo
```

Here is my nightwatch.js file;

```
  {
    "test_settings": {
        "default": {
            "launch_url": "http://localhost",
            "selenium_port": 4444,
            "selenium_host": "localhost",
            "silent": true,
            "firefox_profile": false,
            "chrome_driver": "",
            "ie_driver": "",
            "screenshots": {
                "enabled": false,
                "path": ""
            },
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "firefox",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is too old but I suggest you to try updating the node version

```
# circle.yml
machine:
  node:
    version: 5.8.0
```